# Getting None when scraping for operating income from SEC EDGAR document

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to obtain the latest quarter's operating income/loss from a quarterly filling.

Desired output highlighted in green: [financial statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tePcl.jpg)

Here's the URL of the document that I'm trying to scrape: https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm

If you'd like to see the data point visually, it is in PART I, Item 1. Financial Statements, Operating income.

The HTML code for the figure that I'm trying to get:

```html
<ix:nonfraction id="fact-identifier-125" name="us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss" contextref="FD2019Q3QTD" unitref="usd" decimals="-6" scale="6" format="ixt:numdotdecimal" data-original-id="d305292495e1903-wk-Fact-6250FB76089207E7F73CB52756E0D8D0" continued-taxonomy="false" enabled-taxonomy="true" highlight-taxonomy="false" selected-taxonomy="false" hover-taxonomy="false" onclick="Taxonomies.clickEvent(event, this)" onkeyup="Taxonomies.clickEvent(event, this)" onmouseenter="Taxonomies.enterElement(event, this);" onmouseleave="Taxonomies.leaveElement(event, this);" tabindex="18" isadditionalitemsonly="false">11,544</ix:nonfraction>
```

The code that I used to obtain this data point (11,544).:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm'

response = requests.get(url)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

operatingincomeloss = content.find('ix:nonfraction', attrs={"name": "us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss", "contextref":"FD2019Q3QTD"})

print (operatingincomeloss)
```

I also tried with

```py
operatingincomeloss = content.find('ix:nonfraction', attrs={"name": "us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss"}
```

Eventually, I want to loop through all the relevant fillings to pull this data point. Currently, I'm just getting None. When I CTRl+F through content, I can't find the ix:nonfraction tag as well.

Comment: i still don't understand what is your desired output, can you attach a pic

Comment: Just attached an image sorry. The figure is highlighted in green

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page is loaded via `JavaScript`, I've attached the `XHR` request made and extracted the data required.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select("#d305292495e1903-wk-Fact-6250FB76089207E7F73CB52756E0D8D0"):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
11,544
```

Updated:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction", {'contextref': 'FD2019Q3QTD', 'name': 'us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss'}):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: This was done by selecting a specific ID right? I want to be able to do the same thing repeatedly for other documents that I will loop through. So I won't be able to know the specific ID. That's why I chose to filter by "name": "us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss", "contextref":"FD2019Q3QTD" so it will be replicable  across different fillings. Any idea why mine wouldn't work?

Comment: @moron check my updated answer, searching by `name` and `contextref` will give you an output of 2 numbers because it's present by same attribute.

Answer (score -1):

As @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη said, the page is loaded via `JavaScript`.
I have used the `xhr` request for this code.

Considering the attributes you have used, I have taken `name` attribute only, as `contextref` changes for each element.

You could also change the `name` attribute if you want to loop through other elements.

As you said you want to loop through this tag, I have printed all the output returning in the code below.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for data in soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction', {'name': 'us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss'}):
    print(data.text)
```

Output:

```
11,544
12,612
48,305
54,780
7,442
7,496
26,329
26,580
3,687
3,892
14,371
15,044
3,221
3,414
12,142
15,285
1,795
1,765
7,199
7,193
1,155
1,127
4,811
4,980
17,300
17,694
64,852
69,082
11,544
12,612
48,305
54,780
```

Comment: May I know why is my answer voted down? This isn't a wrong answer right?